# Get minDate from nested array using java stream

Tags: java, stream, hashmap, nested-lists

I have List of MainData `List<MainData>`, I want to be able to get the minimum date with a filter where type is equals to `"S"` or `"A"`. I think the best response type would be a `HashMap<String(type), PojoClass> lowestDateOfTypeSandA`

**Lets say I have**

```
List<MainData> mainDataList contains 3 elements:
pojo1 = mainDataList[0].getSubData().getPojoClass().size() is 2
pojo2 = mainDataList[1].getSubData().getPojoClass().size() is 3
pojo3 = mainDataList[2].getSubData().getPojoClass().size() is 1
```

ex:

- the lowest "S" is in
  `mainDataList[1].getSubData().getPojoClass().get(2)`
- the lowest "A"    is in
  `mainDataList[2].getSubData().getPojoClass().get(0)`

**Structure:**

```
MainData.java
 - SubData getSubData()

SubData.java
 - List<PojoClass> getPojoList()

PojoClass.java
 - XMLGregorianCalendar getdate();
 - String getType();
```

**Convert XMLCalender to Java Date**

```
   public static Date convertXMLGregorianCalendarToDate(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar) {
        return xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
    }
```

I have tried a couple of things but I need to be able to dtream from Maindata so I  get all the other elements as well.

```
Collection<PojoClass> pojoWithMinDate = pojoClassList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        PojoClass::getType,
        Function.identity(),
        (p1, p2) -> p1.getDate() > p2.getDate() ? p1 : p2))
    .values();

   List<PojoClass> result = pojoClassList.stream()
                .filter(p -> "S".equals(p.getType() || "A".equals(p.getType())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your code and discussion here seems unnecessarily complicated. Can you boil this down to a more specific technical question?

Comment: FYI, the terrible `Date` and `XMLGregorianCalendar` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested.

```
Comparator<XMLGregorianCalendar> xgcComp
        = Comparator.comparing(xgc -> xgc.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
Map<String, Optional<PojoClass>> lowestDateOfTypeSAndA = mainDataList.stream()
        .flatMap(md -> md.getSubData().getPojoClass().stream())
        .filter(p -> p.getType().equals("S") || p.getType().equals("A"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PojoClass::getType,
                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(PojoClass::getdate, xgcComp))));
```

The `flatMap` operation turns our strem of `MainData` into a stream of `PojoClass`.

The `groupingBy` operation uses a so.called *downstream collector* to further process each group. In this case into the minimum POJO by date from that group. Since there may be no elements and hence no minimum, an `Optional` is collected into.